# JMeter - How to do setup thread group, many worker threads and then repeat?

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

The current setup is like that:

1. Registration / login (setUp Thread Group) 1 thread, 1 loop
2. spam POST (Thread Group) 100 threads 1000 loops.

Seems simple enough.

But, now I need to do multiple instances in the following order:

Do 1, then do 2. While 2 is spamming, wait 1 minute and then do 1 and then 2. Repeat this for 10 times.

Regardless of whether the 2nd Thread Group is done or not. Every minute, I need the JMeter to register, and if it is successful, spam POST.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Thread Group (1 thread, 1 loop)

   - [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter), condition `${__javaScript(${counter} < 10,)}`

     - [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) configured as:

       [image: JMeter Counter]
     - Your login sampler(s)
     - [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) configured as:

       [image: Test Action - sleep]
     - Another Test Action Sampler configured like:

       [image: JMeter Test Action 2]
2. Second Thread Group. (100 Threads, Loop Count: Forever)

Every minute 1st Thread Group will perform Login for 10 times while 2nd Thread Group will be "spamming", when 1st Thread Group will execute login 10 times the test will finish.

Answer (score 0):

Just create multiple Thread Groups (use 'Duplicate) and add some delayed (+1 min, +2 min, ...) to each of them.